# how to change percentage text's color for piechart in amchart 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts

I am using a piechart from amchart4 for the dark-themed project. where every pie is attached with its percentage like 5%, 10% and so.

As my project's theme is dark & the default color for these percentages is black, I am in need of showing them "white color" can someone please help here is the image. [problem I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7CNZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of **labels** and **ticks**, you need this:

```js
pieSeries.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
pieSeries.ticks.template.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
```

Here is a simple example:

```js
am4core.ready(() => {
  
  let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart);

  chart.data = [
    {
      category: "Category 1",
      value: 10
    },
    {
      category: "Category 2",
      value: 20
    },
    {
      category: "Category 3",
      value: 15
    }
  ];

  let pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
  
  pieSeries.dataFields.value = "value";
  pieSeries.dataFields.category = "category";
  
  // HERE
  pieSeries.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
  pieSeries.ticks.template.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
  
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #1c2023;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, Thanks a lot! @badacadabra